# Can I delete postgis.tar?

Tags: postgis

I installed postgresql 10 and postgis 3.1 on CentOS 7 with yum days ago.

Today I found these files:

```bash
$ cd /data/os_use_disk/tmp2
$ du -sh ./*
571M    ./postgis1.tar
571M    ./postgis2.tar
571M    ./postgis3.tar
571M    ./postgis4.tar
571M    ./postgis5.tar
571M    ./postgis6.tar
571M    ./postgis7.tar
571M    ./postgis8.tar
439M    ./postgis9.tar
```

Can I delete them safely? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using PostGIS as part of your database setup or application, and you have no intention of using it in the future, then it's safe to delete the "postgis.tar" file but make sure you have a backup of your data and configurations especially one related to database functionality